# JavaScript illegal break statement?

Tags: javascript

All I have is

```
        if (arr.length == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("input_table").innerHTML += "<p>Can't sort an empty array, bro!</p>";
            break;
        }
```

and I'm getting an `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement"` error from my Chrome console.

I don't think I need to post my entire code, since context is irrelevant here.

Comment: `break` is only valid within a `switch > case` context or a loop (e.g `for` or `while`)

Comment: If you are trying to return early, change the `break` to a `return`. Otherwise, just remove the `break`.

Comment: No need for the downvote. There's errors in the code, yes, but the question itself is fine.

Comment: `return` may not be valid either, as it only applies within a context of a closure (e.g. a `function`). Soo.. you said the context is irrelevant, but actually the context **is** relevant.

Comment: We need the surrounding code for context.

Answer (score 8):

Break is for loops or switch statements, try a return instead.

Comment: This assumes he's inside a closure to be returned from.

Comment: also worth noting return is not necessary in this example

Comment: Yes, you're both right

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `break` completely. Others have stated to use `return` instead, but that's a bit misleading. You don't need anything, only your logic to tell when to exit (or the closing bracket).